# Enable ecryptfs for all new users, even those authenticating through kerberos and ldap

Tags: ecryptfs, pam, single-sign-on

How do I make sure that all users have their home directory encrypted when the login for the first time?

I have setup pam to use Kerberos authentication and LDAP authorization (which I think should not really have any effect on ecryptfs).

I have also setup pam-mkhomedir to create the home directories from /etc/skel in which I have placed some standard configurations.

Looking at the .ecryptfs directory in one user account that already has ecryptfs enabled, there are some user-specific configurations, such as the mountpoint (set to /home/d_inevitable) for example, which would be no good in /etc/skel.

Also the configurations in /etc/skel would need to be copied **after** the home directory has been mounted with ecryptfs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have managed to get it to work using pam_exec:

1. Create a script to setup ecryptfs for all new users in `/etc/security/ecryptfs`:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   home=`eval echo ~$PAM_USER`
   ecryptfs=/home/.ecryptfs/$PAM_USER/.ecryptfs

   read password

   if [ -d $ecryptfs ];  then
       # ecryptfs is set
       echo "Ecryptfs is already configured"
       exit 0
   elif [ `id -u` == 0 ]; then
       # Setup ecryptfs and make home
       umask 077
       mkdir -p $home
       group=`id -gn $PAM_USER`
       chown $PAM_USER:$group $home

       ecryptfs-setup-private -u $PAM_USER -l "$password" -b --nopwcheck
       exit 0
   else
       # NOT ROOT
       echo "Cannot login with 'su' for the first time"
       exit 1
   fi
   ```

   Make sure the script is executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod a+rx /etc/security/ecryptfs
   ```
2. Add entry to execute it with pam_exec on auth:

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/pam.d/common_auth
   ```

   Add the following lines:

   ```
   auth    required        pam_exec.so     expose_authtok /etc/security/ecryptfs
   auth    optional        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
   ```

   The `pam_exec` is set to required, because it will not setup ecryptfs if the script doesn't run as root. This is the case if `su` is used from a non-root user. So if ecryptfs is not setup and `su` is used (that is when the user attempts to login for the first time using `su`) then his will get refused. As such we ensure that the user cannot login without an ecryptfs setup.
3. Create another script to populate the home directory in place of pam_mkhomedir

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/security/mkhome
   ```

   This script will copy everything in /etc/skel if the file .donotremove doesn't exist.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   cd ~

   if [ ! -f .donotremove ] ; then
       echo Copying /etc/skel
       cp -ra /etc/skel/* ~
       touch .donotremove
   fi
   ```

   Also make sure this file is executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod a+rx /etc/security/mkhome
   ```
4. Add another entry to execute this script on a session

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/pam.d/common_session
   ```

   Add the following lines:

   ```
   session optional        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
   session optional        pam_exec.so     seteuid /etc/security/mkhome
   ```

Now LDAP users can login and have an ecryptfs encrypted home directory.

### Update

Instead of editing the files in `/etc/pam.d` directly (which is generally not recommended), it is better to apply the settings as a [PAMConfig](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PAMConfigFrameworkSpec) profile.

Just paste this code into a new file `/usr/share/pam-configs/ecryptfs-nonlocal`:

```
Name: Enable EcryptFS for users from remote directories such as LDAP.
Default: no
Priority: 0
Conflicts: ecryptfs-utils
Auth-Type: Additional
Auth-Final:
    required    pam_exec.so expose_authtok /etc/security/ecryptfs
    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
Session-Type: Additional
Session-Final:
    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
    optional    pam_exec.so seteuid /etc/security/mkhome
Password-Type: Additional
Password-Final:
    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so
```

And then run `pam-auth-update`:

[image: pam-auth-update]

Check `Enable EcryptFS for users from remote directories such as LDAP.` and make sure that `eCryptfs Key/Mount Management` is **unchecked**. Leave all other options up to your preferences.

This will make sure that relevant configs in `/etc/pam.d` are applied and that they stay there.