# ecryptfs-setup-private login passphrase incorrect

Tags: password, ecryptfs

I'm trying to access my former home folder. When I run `ecryptfs-setup-private`, I am asked for my login passphrase which returns `ERROR: Your login passphrase is incorrect`. I have tried both, my login-pw for that account, and the home-folder pw Ubuntu gave me after installing it. What can I do?

Comment: I have the same problem. I thought it was because I changed my password with `passwd` but switching back to the old password doesn't solve the problem. I think that there is a keyring that stores some old passphrase, the problem is to find it!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `ecryptfs-setup-private` is not too good in checking password of LDAP users. Passing `--nopwcheck` to the script will skip the password check.

Comment: related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ecryptfs/+bug/1630477  | https://askubuntu.com/questions/111803/enable-ecryptfs-for-all-new-users-even-those-authenticating-through-kerberos-an